# what preposition is particularly followed by ‘communicate’ in terms of conveying message to the reader?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I find the verb ‘communicate’ a bit confusing when it comes to use preposition. Can I use ‘with’ when accompanying by someone/something? For example:

> Poets communicate **with** poetic devices. Writers communicate **through** metaphors.

Here, **with** and **through** have been used as prepositions after communicate. Can I say

> I can’t communicate **with** sign language

or

> Wordsworth communicates his feelings **in** literary language?

Answer (score 3):

All of the examples you gave sound correct to native speakers, though a nitpicker might suggest:

Use "with" to introduce the receiver of the communication or some noun describing the act of communicating:

> He communicated with her.
>   He communicated with a sense of urgency the problem before him.

Use "in" to refer to the language being used:

> He communicated in Spanish.

I would also suggest you use "in" to refer to manners of speaking:

> He communicated in hushed tones

not usually "he communicated using hushed tones," which would be a more technical description.

Use "using" to refer to a device formally:

> He communicated using a phone.

You can also use "to" to introduce the receiver formally or in the context of a very specific thing being communicated:

> He communicated to her the password.

Finally, you can use "on" to say

> communicate on the phone.

I don't think I can identify every variation.

Comment: You would have to stop and deliberately think about it to notice that it sounds odd, but I suppose I agree with you. Use "with" to introduce the receiver of the communication or some noun describing the act of communicating: "He communicated with her." "He communicated with a sense of urgency the problem before him." Use "in" to refer to the language being used: "He communicated in Spanish." Use "using" to refer to a device: "He communicated using a phone." These are just guidelines.

Comment: You can also use "to" to describe the receiver: "He communicated to her," though that has more a sense of formality of exchange of information. I would also suggest you use "in" to refer to manners of speaking: "He communicated in hushed tones," not usually "he communicated using hushed tones," which would be a more technical description. Finally, you can say "communicate on the phone." I don't think I can identify every variation.